# Using the CLT to determine limit

Tags: probability-theory

$Y_1,Y_2,....$ is a seq. of i.i.d r.v.'s with $E[Y_i]=\mu$ and $Var[Y_i]=\sigma^{2}$.

Let $t\geq 0$, and define $X_n(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} Y_i$.

I want to show that $\frac{1}{n}X_n(t) \xrightarrow{\text{$L^{2}$}} h(t)$ for some function $h$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}$, and determine that function $h$.

I was thinking that $L^{2}$ convergence implies that: $\lim_{n\to\infty} E[|\frac{1}{n}X_n(t)-h(t)|^{2}]=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}X_n(t)-h(t)=0 \Rightarrow \mu-h(t)=0 \iff h(t)=\mu$.

Can I use this, or did I miss something?

Comment: Note that the sum in $X_n(t)$ has $[nt]$ elements, not $n$ so by the CLT $\frac{X_n(t)}{[nt]} \to N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $\frac{X_n(t)}{n} = t \cdot\frac{[nt]}{nt}\cdot \frac{X_n(t)}{[nt]} $

Comment: I don't really follow...Doesn't the CLT tell us that the mean of the sample average $\frac{1}{n} X_n(t) \rightarrow N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n})$. Does the $[nt]$ elements matter? Since $t\geq 0$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: It's $\frac{1}{2}$. Even if it doesn't matter, don't we have $(\frac{n}{2} +1) 1's$, since you are summing from $k=0$ ..or am I missing something?

Comment: I still don't understand why you start with dividng by [nt], and obtain $\frac{X_n(t)}{[nt]} \rightarrow N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$...

Comment: Doesnt the CLT say that it converge to $N(\mu,\sigma^{2}/M)$ ?

Comment: I missed a $1/M$ there (but to late to change the comment so I deleted it. The same typo is also in the first comment).

Comment: Ah okay.  So does this work?

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} X_n(t) -g(t)=0 \iff \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{[nt]}{n} \frac{1}{[nt]} X_n(t) - g(t)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{[nt]}{n} \mu -g(t)=0 \iff g(t)=\frac{[nt]}{n}\mu$ ?